# Alternative definition of vector addition in $\Bbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Vector addition in $\Bbb{R^n}$ are naturally defined in a way that matches with the physical sense of displacement (i.e. adding ordered pairs or combining arrows). And axioms for any abstract vector spaces are made to follow the rule of vectors in $\Bbb{R^n}$. So my question is:

> Is there any other ways to define vector addition in $\Bbb{R^n}$, such that all the axioms required are satisfied? If not, is there a proof that one cannot do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is, but I couldn't tell you *exactly* what that addition looks like. Here is a construction, though: pick a bijection $f:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^n$ with $m\neq n$. Now define a new addition $\oplus$ and scalar multiplication $\odot$ on $\Bbb R^n$ as
$$
a\oplus b=f(f^{-1}(a)+f^{-1}(b)),\\ r\odot a=f(r\cdot f^{-1}(a))
$$
This makes $\Bbb R^n$ into an $m$-dimensional vector space. Informally, it's just $\Bbb R^m$ where all the elements have changed names to arbitrary elements of $\Bbb R^n$, without changing any structure.

Comment: Very interesting answer :)